# how to dataurl with knockout data-bind

Tags: knockout.js, data-url

How to display an image in knockout using dataurl?

I have an observable in knockout with value set as dataurl for an image. I want to bind this image to html-5 data-bind attribute of span element.

Currently, the image is not getting displayed. Can anyone help me with the syntax?

Sample code:

```
'<'span style="display:block; width:96px; height:95px;" data-bind="style:{backgroundImage: 'url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA'}"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply missing the closing `)` of the `url`. Try this:

```
<span style="display:block; width:96px; height:95px;"
      data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA)' }"></span>
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J8VNY/3/

Comment: The sample code which i pasted was too long so made it short by removing characters ,while doing so also removed the closing ) .
Your code worked for me thanks...